# Horizontal/Vertical (Anchor) Page Content Scrolling On Link Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

Similar questions, if not exact questions like this have been asked but not often and the answers I have tried to alter with but have had no luck what-so-ever.

Basically, I want to be able to make the content part of my page (so the header remains on each page) change and I'm not sure if this is with anchors using only one html page or if it's multiple html pages or really how it's done at all. Been looking for over 5 hours but to no avail.

I came across this site looking for an answer and it has exactly what I am looking for http://www.aivahthemes.com/themes/gracious/index.html

I looked everywhere and found sites where it did similar things but if you went right by two pages and then went back to the original page, you would see the middle page on the way back. That site above does NOT do this and actually hides the pages between links somehow which is amazing.

This is a bit vague as I havn't posted any code but literally all the code I tried was just from previous questions and it was just me trying to adapt half-answers to what I wanted.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm stumped!

Edit:
*Looked a bit more into detail, does look like one whole single HTML page. Why was it so quick to load though if it was an entire page? Thought that would have been a long process.

Edit2:
*Is it also possible to achieve this 'style' by doing it vertically?

Answer (score 0):

The site you listed uses hashes in the URL. You can add them dynamically with javascript or just by using plain anchors. Hash in the url will save it in the browser history and the back/forward buttons will work fine. The only tricky part is reading the hash, which is pretty much straight forward with `window.location.hash` - it returns everything after '#' sign.

The script for animation/getting pages would be a little bit more complex, but as I see it's all based on getting the right `<div id="HASH_FROM_URL">`, moving it to 'left: -9999px' and then animating to main container's `offsetLeft`.